# foreach with two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

i have problem i need foreach two arrays to get from two jsons information to one foreach. now code looks like

```
foreach($videoList->items as $item){
```

But i need two arrays like this

```
foreach($videoList->items as $item) and ($videoViews->items as $items){
```

Code:

```
foreach($videoList->items as $item){    
        if(isset($item->id->videoId) && ($items->statistics->viewCount)){
            echo '<div class="video">           
                    <iframe width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <h5>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h5>
                    <h5>'.$items->statistics->viewCount.' &nbsp; '.$items->statistics->likeCount.' &nbsp; '.$items->statistics->dislikeCount.'</h5>
                </div>';
        }

    }
```

Comment: The foreach loop through only one array. You should use two foreach for this purpose

Comment: Or merge the data into a single array somehow.

Comment: but i have 2 jsons and i need get from 2 jsons information to one div.

Comment: Why not just use a for loop? Should work fine unless there’s more values in one array than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming that `$videoList` and `$videoViews` have common keys, in which case you can rewrite your loop as

```
foreach($videoList->items as $key => $item) {    
    if(isset($item->id->videoId) && ($videoViews->{$key}->statistics->viewCount)) {
        echo '<div class="video">           
              <iframe width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              <h5>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h5>
              <h5>'.$videoViews->{$key}->statistics->viewCount.' &nbsp; ' . 
                    $videoViews->{$key}->statistics->likeCount.' &nbsp; ' . 
                    $videoViews->{$key}->statistics->dislikeCount.'</h5>
              </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ->
if(isset($item->id->videoId) && ($videoViews[$key]->statistics->viewCount)) {

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise `$videoViews` was an object. See my edit.

Comment: @Mirin did this help?